# dovecot with LDAP can't find userPassword

Tags: ldap, dovecot, debian-stretch, authorization

I'm new to LDAP and I'm trying to use it with Dovecot for authentication.  When I test out my setup with Telnet and IMAP, it reports 'userPassword not found'.  However a simple search using the same criteria brings up the userPassword correctly.
Here's my **database setup** (olcDatabase={1}mdb.ldif)

```
    # AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 d372c2c5
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * non
e
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by * read
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcRootDN: cn=diradmin,dc=example,dc=com
olcDbCheckpoint: 512 30
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
olcDbIndex: cn,uid eq
olcDbIndex: uidNumber,gidNumber eq
olcDbIndex: member,memberUid eq
olcDbMaxSize: 1073741824
structuralObjectClass: olcMdbConfig
entryUUID: fed6b8a2-97ef-1038-8643-a149e041a590
creatorsName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
createTimestamp: 20181219153919Z
olcRootPW:: cnZ3MTIz
entryCSN: 20181220125956.316222Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20181220125956Z
```

This is the database (**ldapsearch output**)

```
    # extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=example,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# example.com
dn: dc=example,dc=com
dc: example
o: Example Company
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization

# diradmin, example.com
dn: cn=diradmin,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: top
cn: diradmin

# Domains, example.com
dn: ou=Domains,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Domains

# Users, example.com
dn: ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Users

# Services, example.com
dn: ou=Services,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: Services

# rvw.xxxxxx.org, Domains, example.com
dn: dc=rvw.xxxxxx.org,ou=Domains,dc=example,dc=com
dc: rvw.xxxxxx.org
objectClass: dNSDomain
objectClass: top
o: postfixUser
userPassword:: e0NSWVBUfXdRd0VQdGh3dEtUYTY=

# Richard Williams, Users, example.com
dn: cn=Richard Williams,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
cn: Richard Williams
mailacceptinggeneralid: rvw.xxxxxx.org
maildrop: richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org
mailEnabled: TRUE
mailGidNumber: 5000
mailUidNumber: 5000
objectClass: extensibleObject
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: PostfixBookMailAccount
objectClass: postfixUser
objectClass: top
sn: Williams
uid: richardwiliams
userPassword:: e01ENX10YTc1cE80QjNwOWtJRFFuVUsxeUpRPT0=
mail: richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org
mailAlias: richard@rvw.xxxxxx.org
mailAlias: postmaster@rvw.xxxxxx.org
mailAlias: abuse@rvw.xxxxxx.org
mailHomeDirectory: /home/vmail
mailStorageDirectory: maildir:/home/vmail/richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org/Maild
 ir
uniqueIdentifier: richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org

# phamm, example.com
dn: cn=phamm,dc=example,dc=com
cn: phamm
objectClass: organizationalRole
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: top
userPassword:: e01ENX10YTc1cE80QjNwOWtJRFFuVUsxeUpRPT0=

# dovecot, Services, example.com
dn: uid=dovecot,ou=Services,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: account
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: top
userPassword:: e01ENX10YTc1cE80QjNwOWtJRFFuVUsxeUpRPT0=
uid: dovecot

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 10
# numEntries: 9
```

**The log shows**

```
    Jan  5 16:01:58 broadband dovecot: auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth/libauthdb_ldap.so
Jan  5 16:01:58 broadband dovecot: auth: Debug: Read auth token secret from /var/run/dovecot/auth-token-secret.dat
Jan  5 16:01:58 broadband dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=1232)
Jan  5 16:02:24 broadband dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#0111#011PLAIN#011service=imap#011secured#011session=j1UfH7h+8tgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB#011lip=::1#011rip=::1#011lport=143#011rport=55538#011resp=<hidden>
Jan  5 16:02:24 broadband dovecot: auth: Debug: ldap(richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org,::1,<j1UfH7h+8tgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>): pass search: base=ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com scope=subtree filter=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org)) fields=mail,userPassword
Jan  5 16:02:24 broadband dovecot: auth: Debug: ldap(richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org,::1,<j1UfH7h+8tgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>): result: mail=richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org; mail unused
Jan  5 16:02:24 broadband dovecot: auth: Debug: ldap(richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org,::1,<j1UfH7h+8tgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>): result: mail=richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org; userPassword missing
Jan  5 16:02:24 broadband dovecot: auth: ldap(richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org,::1,<j1UfH7h+8tgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>): No password returned (and no nopassword)
Jan  5 16:02:26 broadband dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL#0111#011user=richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org
Jan  5 16:02:31 broadband dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 7 secs): user=<richardwilliams@rvw.xxxxxx.org>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<j1UfH7h+8tgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
```

Here's the **dovecot-ldap.conf.ext** file

```
    # This file is commonly accessed via passdb {} or userdb {} section in
# conf.d/auth-ldap.conf.ext

# This file is opened as root, so it should be owned by root and mode 0600.
#
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/LDAP
#
# NOTE: If you're not using authentication binds, you'll need to give
# dovecot-auth read access to userPassword field in the LDAP server.
# With OpenLDAP this is done by modifying /etc/ldap/slapd.conf. There should
# already be something like this:

# access to attribute=userPassword
#        by dn="<dovecot's dn>" read # add this
#        by anonymous auth
#        by self write
#        by * none

# Space separated list of LDAP hosts to use. host:port is allowed too.
hosts = 127.0.0.1

# LDAP URIs to use. You can use this instead of hosts list. Note that this
# setting isn't supported by all LDAP libraries.
#uris = 

# Distinguished Name - the username used to login to the LDAP server.
# Leave it commented out to bind anonymously (useful with auth_bind=yes).
#dn = 

# Password for LDAP server, if dn is specified.
#dnpass = 

# Use SASL binding instead of the simple binding. Note that this changes
# ldap_version automatically to be 3 if it's lower.
#sasl_bind = no
# SASL mechanism name to use.
#sasl_mech =
# SASL realm to use.
#sasl_realm =
# SASL authorization ID, ie. the dnpass is for this "master user", but the
# dn is still the logged in user. Normally you want to keep this empty.
#sasl_authz_id =

# Use TLS to connect to the LDAP server.
#tls = no
# TLS options, currently supported only with OpenLDAP:
#tls_ca_cert_file =
#tls_ca_cert_dir =
#tls_cipher_suite =
# TLS cert/key is used only if LDAP server requires a client certificate.
#tls_cert_file =
#tls_key_file =
# Valid values: never, hard, demand, allow, try
#tls_require_cert =

# Use the given ldaprc path.
#ldaprc_path =

# LDAP library debug level as specified by LDAP_DEBUG_* in ldap_log.h.
# -1 = everything. You may need to recompile OpenLDAP with debugging enabled
# to get enough output.
debug_level = 0 

# Use authentication binding for verifying password's validity. This works by
# logging into LDAP server using the username and password given by client.
# The pass_filter is used to find the DN for the user. Note that the pass_attrs
# is still used, only the password field is ignored in it. Before doing any
# search, the binding is switched back to the default DN.
auth_bind = no 

# If authentication binding is used, you can save one LDAP request per login
# if users' DN can be specified with a common template. The template can use
# the standard %variables (see user_filter). Note that you can't
# use any pass_attrs if you use this setting.
#
# If you use this setting, it's a good idea to use a different
# dovecot-ldap.conf.ext for userdb (it can even be a symlink, just as long as
# the filename is different in userdb's args). That way one connection is used
# only for LDAP binds and another connection is used for user lookups.
# Otherwise the binding is changed to the default DN before each user lookup.
#
# For example:
#   auth_bind_userdn = cn=%u,ou=people,o=org
#
#auth_bind_userdn =

# LDAP protocol version to use. Likely 2 or 3.
ldap_version = 3

# LDAP base. %variables can be used here.
# For example: dc=mail, dc=example, dc=org
base = ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com

# Dereference: never, searching, finding, always
deref = never

# Search scope: base, onelevel, subtree
scope = subtree

# User attributes are given in LDAP-name=dovecot-internal-name list. The
# internal names are:
#   uid - System UID
#   gid - System GID
#   home - Home directory
#   mail - Mail location
#
# There are also other special fields which can be returned, see
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/UserDatabase/ExtraFields
user_attrs = homeDirectory=home,uidNumber=uid,gidNumber=gid

# Filter for user lookup. Some variables can be used (see
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Variables for full list):
#   %u - username
#   %n - user part in user@domain, same as %u if there's no domain
#   %d - domain part in user@domain, empty if user there's no domain
user_filter = (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=%u))

# Password checking attributes:
#  user: Virtual user name (user@domain), if you wish to change the
#        user-given username to something else
#  password: Password, may optionally start with {type}, eg. {crypt}
# There are also other special fields which can be returned, see
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/ExtraFields
pass_attrs = mail=user,userPassword=password

# If you wish to avoid two LDAP lookups (passdb + userdb), you can use
# userdb prefetch instead of userdb ldap in dovecot.conf. In that case you'll
# also have to include user_attrs in pass_attrs field prefixed with "userdb_"
# string. For example:
#pass_attrs = uid=user,userPassword=password,\
#  homeDirectory=userdb_home,uidNumber=userdb_uid,gidNumber=userdb_gid

# Filter for password lookups
pass_filter = (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=%u))

# Attributes and filter to get a list of all users
#iterate_attrs = uid=user
#iterate_filter = (objectClass=posixAccount)

# Default password scheme. "{scheme}" before password overrides this.
# List of supported schemes is in: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication
default_pass_scheme = md5
```

**auth-ldap.conf.ext**

```
    # This file is commonly accessed via passdb {} or userdb {} section in
# conf.d/auth-ldap.conf.ext

# This file is opened as root, so it should be owned by root and mode 0600.
#
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/LDAP
#
# NOTE: If you're not using authentication binds, you'll need to give
# dovecot-auth read access to userPassword field in the LDAP server.
# With OpenLDAP this is done by modifying /etc/ldap/slapd.conf. There should
# already be something like this:

# access to attribute=userPassword
#        by dn="<dovecot's dn>" read # add this
#        by anonymous auth
#        by self write
#        by * none

# Space separated list of LDAP hosts to use. host:port is allowed too.
hosts = 127.0.0.1

# LDAP URIs to use. You can use this instead of hosts list. Note that this
# setting isn't supported by all LDAP libraries.
#uris = 

# Distinguished Name - the username used to login to the LDAP server.
# Leave it commented out to bind anonymously (useful with auth_bind=yes).
#dn = 

# Password for LDAP server, if dn is specified.
#dnpass = 

# Use SASL binding instead of the simple binding. Note that this changes
# ldap_version automatically to be 3 if it's lower.
#sasl_bind = no
# SASL mechanism name to use.
#sasl_mech =
# SASL realm to use.
#sasl_realm =
# SASL authorization ID, ie. the dnpass is for this "master user", but the
# dn is still the logged in user. Normally you want to keep this empty.
#sasl_authz_id =

# Use TLS to connect to the LDAP server.
#tls = no
# TLS options, currently supported only with OpenLDAP:
#tls_ca_cert_file =
#tls_ca_cert_dir =
#tls_cipher_suite =
# TLS cert/key is used only if LDAP server requires a client certificate.
#tls_cert_file =
#tls_key_file =
# Valid values: never, hard, demand, allow, try
#tls_require_cert =

# Use the given ldaprc path.
#ldaprc_path =

# LDAP library debug level as specified by LDAP_DEBUG_* in ldap_log.h.
# -1 = everything. You may need to recompile OpenLDAP with debugging enabled
# to get enough output.
debug_level = 0 

# Use authentication binding for verifying password's validity. This works by
# logging into LDAP server using the username and password given by client.
# The pass_filter is used to find the DN for the user. Note that the pass_attrs
# is still used, only the password field is ignored in it. Before doing any
# search, the binding is switched back to the default DN.
auth_bind = no 

# If authentication binding is used, you can save one LDAP request per login
# if users' DN can be specified with a common template. The template can use
# the standard %variables (see user_filter). Note that you can't
# use any pass_attrs if you use this setting.
#
# If you use this setting, it's a good idea to use a different
# dovecot-ldap.conf.ext for userdb (it can even be a symlink, just as long as
# the filename is different in userdb's args). That way one connection is used
# only for LDAP binds and another connection is used for user lookups.
# Otherwise the binding is changed to the default DN before each user lookup.
#
# For example:
#   auth_bind_userdn = cn=%u,ou=people,o=org
#
#auth_bind_userdn =

# LDAP protocol version to use. Likely 2 or 3.
ldap_version = 3

# LDAP base. %variables can be used here.
# For example: dc=mail, dc=example, dc=org
base = ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com

# Dereference: never, searching, finding, always
deref = never

# Search scope: base, onelevel, subtree
scope = subtree

# User attributes are given in LDAP-name=dovecot-internal-name list. The
# internal names are:
#   uid - System UID
#   gid - System GID
#   home - Home directory
#   mail - Mail location
#
# There are also other special fields which can be returned, see
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/UserDatabase/ExtraFields
user_attrs = homeDirectory=home,uidNumber=uid,gidNumber=gid

# Filter for user lookup. Some variables can be used (see
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Variables for full list):
#   %u - username
#   %n - user part in user@domain, same as %u if there's no domain
#   %d - domain part in user@domain, empty if user there's no domain
user_filter = (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=%u))

# Password checking attributes:
#  user: Virtual user name (user@domain), if you wish to change the
#        user-given username to something else
#  password: Password, may optionally start with {type}, eg. {crypt}
# There are also other special fields which can be returned, see
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/ExtraFields
pass_attrs = mail=user,userPassword=password

# If you wish to avoid two LDAP lookups (passdb + userdb), you can use
# userdb prefetch instead of userdb ldap in dovecot.conf. In that case you'll
# also have to include user_attrs in pass_attrs field prefixed with "userdb_"
# string. For example:
#pass_attrs = uid=user,userPassword=password,\
#  homeDirectory=userdb_home,uidNumber=userdb_uid,gidNumber=userdb_gid

# Filter for password lookups
pass_filter = (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=%u))

# Attributes and filter to get a list of all users
#iterate_attrs = uid=user
#iterate_filter = (objectClass=posixAccount)

# Default password scheme. "{scheme}" before password overrides this.
# List of supported schemes is in: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication
default_pass_scheme = md5
```

**10-master.conf**

```
    #default_process_limit = 100
#default_client_limit = 1000

# Default VSZ (virtual memory size) limit for service processes. This is mainly
# intended to catch and kill processes that leak memory before they eat up
# everything.
#default_vsz_limit = 256M

# Login user is internally used by login processes. This is the most untrusted
# user in Dovecot system. It shouldn't have access to anything at all.
#default_login_user = dovenull

# Internal user is used by unprivileged processes. It should be separate from
# login user, so that login processes can't disturb other processes.
#default_internal_user = dovecot

service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    #port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    #port = 993
    #ssl = yes
  }

  # Number of connections to handle before starting a new process. Typically
  # the only useful values are 0 (unlimited) or 1. 1 is more secure, but 0
  # is faster. <doc/wiki/LoginProcess.txt>
  #service_count = 1

  # Number of processes to always keep waiting for more connections.
  #process_min_avail = 0

  # If you set service_count=0, you probably need to grow this.
  #vsz_limit = $default_vsz_limit
}

service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    #port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    #port = 995
    #ssl = yes
  }
}

service lmtp {
  unix_listener lmtp {
    #mode = 0666
  }

  # Create inet listener only if you can't use the above UNIX socket
  #inet_listener lmtp {
    # Avoid making LMTP visible for the entire internet
    #address =
    #port = 
  #}
}

service imap {
  # Most of the memory goes to mmap()ing files. You may need to increase this
  # limit if you have huge mailboxes.
  #vsz_limit = $default_vsz_limit

  # Max. number of IMAP processes (connections)
  #process_limit = 1024
}

service pop3 {
  # Max. number of POP3 processes (connections)
  #process_limit = 1024
}

service auth {
  # auth_socket_path points to this userdb socket by default. It's typically
  # used by dovecot-lda, doveadm, possibly imap process, etc. Users that have
  # full permissions to this socket are able to get a list of all usernames and
  # get the results of everyone's userdb lookups.
  #
  # The default 0666 mode allows anyone to connect to the socket, but the
  # userdb lookups will succeed only if the userdb returns an "uid" field that
  # matches the caller process's UID. Also if caller's uid or gid matches the
  # socket's uid or gid the lookup succeeds. Anything else causes a failure.
  #
  # To give the caller full permissions to lookup all users, set the mode to
  # something else than 0666 and Dovecot lets the kernel enforce the
  # permissions (e.g. 0777 allows everyone full permissions).
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
    group = vmail
  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }

  # Auth process is run as this user.
  # user = $default_internal_user
}

service auth-worker {
  # Auth worker process is run as root by default, so that it can access
  # /etc/shadow. If this isn't necessary, the user should be changed to
  # $default_internal_user.
  #user = root
}

service dict {
  # If dict proxy is used, mail processes should have access to its socket.
  # For example: mode=0660, group=vmail and global mail_access_groups=vmail
  unix_listener dict {
    #mode = 0600
    #user = 
    #group = 
  }
}
```

and **10-auth.conf**

```
##
## Authentication processes
##

# Disable LOGIN command and all other plaintext authentications unless
# SSL/TLS is used (LOGINDISABLED capability). Note that if the remote IP
# matches the local IP (ie. you're connecting from the same computer), the
# connection is considered secure and plaintext authentication is allowed.
# See also ssl=required setting.
#disable_plaintext_auth = yes

# Authentication cache size (e.g. 10M). 0 means it's disabled. Note that
# bsdauth, PAM and vpopmail require cache_key to be set for caching to be used.
#auth_cache_size = 0
# Time to live for cached data. After TTL expires the cached record is no
# longer used, *except* if the main database lookup returns internal failure.
# We also try to handle password changes automatically: If user's previous
# authentication was successful, but this one wasn't, the cache isn't used.
# For now this works only with plaintext authentication.
#auth_cache_ttl = 1 hour
# TTL for negative hits (user not found, password mismatch).
# 0 disables caching them completely.
#auth_cache_negative_ttl = 1 hour

# Space separated list of realms for SASL authentication mechanisms that need
# them. You can leave it empty if you don't want to support multiple realms.
# Many clients simply use the first one listed here, so keep the default realm
# first.
#auth_realms =

# Default realm/domain to use if none was specified. This is used for both
# SASL realms and appending @domain to username in plaintext logins.
#auth_default_realm = 

# List of allowed characters in username. If the user-given username contains
# a character not listed in here, the login automatically fails. This is just
# an extra check to make sure user can't exploit any potential quote escaping
# vulnerabilities with SQL/LDAP databases. If you want to allow all characters,
# set this value to empty.
#auth_username_chars = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890.-_@

# Username character translations before it's looked up from databases. The
# value contains series of from -> to characters. For example "#@/@" means
# that '#' and '/' characters are translated to '@'.
#auth_username_translation =

# Username formatting before it's looked up from databases. You can use
# the standard variables here, eg. %Lu would lowercase the username, %n would
# drop away the domain if it was given, or "%n-AT-%d" would change the '@' into
# "-AT-". This translation is done after auth_username_translation changes.
#auth_username_format = %Lu

# If you want to allow master users to log in by specifying the master
# username within the normal username string (ie. not using SASL mechanism's
# support for it), you can specify the separator character here. The format
# is then <username><separator><master username>. UW-IMAP uses "*" as the
# separator, so that could be a good choice.
#auth_master_user_separator =

# Username to use for users logging in with ANONYMOUS SASL mechanism
#auth_anonymous_username = anonymous

# Maximum number of dovecot-auth worker processes. They're used to execute
# blocking passdb and userdb queries (eg. MySQL and PAM). They're
# automatically created and destroyed as needed.
#auth_worker_max_count = 30

# Host name to use in GSSAPI principal names. The default is to use the
# name returned by gethostname(). Use "$ALL" (with quotes) to allow all keytab
# entries.
#auth_gssapi_hostname =

# Kerberos keytab to use for the GSSAPI mechanism. Will use the system
# default (usually /etc/krb5.keytab) if not specified. You may need to change
# the auth service to run as root to be able to read this file.
#auth_krb5_keytab = 

# Do NTLM and GSS-SPNEGO authentication using Samba's winbind daemon and
# ntlm_auth helper. <doc/wiki/Authentication/Mechanisms/Winbind.txt>
#auth_use_winbind = no

# Path for Samba's ntlm_auth helper binary.
#auth_winbind_helper_path = /usr/bin/ntlm_auth

# Time to delay before replying to failed authentications.
#auth_failure_delay = 2 secs

# Require a valid SSL client certificate or the authentication fails.
#auth_ssl_require_client_cert = no

# Take the username from client's SSL certificate, using 
# X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID() which returns the subject's DN's
# CommonName. 
#auth_ssl_username_from_cert = no

# Space separated list of wanted authentication mechanisms:
#   plain login digest-md5 cram-md5 ntlm rpa apop anonymous gssapi otp skey
#   gss-spnego
# NOTE: See also disable_plaintext_auth setting.
auth_mechanisms = plain login

##
## Password and user databases
##

#
# Password database is used to verify user's password (and nothing more).
# You can have multiple passdbs and userdbs. This is useful if you want to
# allow both system users (/etc/passwd) and virtual users to login without
# duplicating the system users into virtual database.
#
# <doc/wiki/PasswordDatabase.txt>
#
# User database specifies where mails are located and what user/group IDs
# own them. For single-UID configuration use "static" userdb.
#
# <doc/wiki/UserDatabase.txt>

#!include auth-deny.conf.ext
#!include auth-master.conf.ext

#!include auth-system.conf.ext
#!include auth-sql.conf.ext
!include auth-ldap.conf.ext
#!include auth-passwdfile.conf.ext
#!include auth-checkpassword.conf.ext
#!include auth-vpopmail.conf.ext
#!include auth-static.conf.ext
```

I'm sure there's just a simple mistake but I'm not able to spot it.  all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Duh! It's the olcAccess on the userPassword that's hiding it!  sorry to have wasted time on this.